# Redis version history and End of Life

Tags: redis

What is the end of life date for Redis versions.

Is there any official document announcing the end of life date for Redis versions.

Comment: by https://www.versio.io/product-release-end-of-life-eol-Redis-Redis.html only version 7.0 and 6.2 are supported now, i am correct ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to [Redis Enterprise Software](https://redis.com/redis-enterprise-software/overview/):

- The official page is here: https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/administering/product-lifecycle/
- The official page for modules is here: https://docs.redis.com/latest/modules/modules-lifecycle/

For Open Source Redis, the official details are here https://redis.io/docs/about/releases/ :

> As a rule, **older versions are not supported** as we try very hard to
> make the Redis API mostly backward compatible.
>
> Upgrading to newer versions is the recommended approach and is usually
> trivial.
>
> The latest stable release is always fully supported and maintained.
>
> Two additional versions receive maintenance only, meaning that only
> fixes for critical bugs and major security issues are committed and
> released as patches:
>
> The previous minor version of the latest stable release. The previous
> stable major release. For example, consider the following hypothetical
> versions: 1.2, 2.0, 2.2, 3.0, 3.2.
>
> **When version 2.2 is the latest stable release, both 2.0 and 1.2 are**
> **maintained**.
>
> **Once version 3.0.0 replaces 2.2 as the latest stable, versions 2.0 and**
> **2.2 are maintained, whereas version 1.x reaches its end of life.**
>
> This process repeats with version 3.2.0, after which only versions 2.2
> and 3.0 are maintained.
>
> The above are guidelines rather than rules set in stone and will not
> replace common sense.

Comment: the above links are for Redis Enterprise Software and the Redis Open Source Software ?